# Foreign key constraints failure when cross updating between two databases

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have two databases (com and usa) with a table with the following schema:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `eav_attribute` (
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Attribute Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute Code',
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_CODE` (`entity_type_id`,`attribute_code`),
  KEY `IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=212 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Eav Attribute'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to make the attribute_ids of USA the same as COM (where code + type match). This query shows my expected result by joining the two tables:

```
SELECT usa_attribute.attribute_id,
       usa_attribute.entity_type_id,
       usa_attribute.attribute_code,
       com_attribute.attribute_id,
       com_attribute.entity_type_id,
       com_attribute.attribute_code
FROM eav_attribute usa_attribute
LEFT JOIN com.eav_attribute com_attribute
          ON ( usa_attribute.entity_type_id = com_attribute.entity_type_id
           AND usa_attribute.attribute_code = com_attribute.attribute_code );

+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code                 | attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code                 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+
|          615 |              1 | confirmation                   |           16 |              1 | confirmation                   |
|          616 |              1 | created_at                     |          481 |              1 | created_at                     |
|          602 |              1 | created_in                     |            3 |              1 | created_in                     |
|          612 |              1 | default_billing                |           13 |              1 | default_billing                |
|          613 |              1 | default_shipping               |           14 |              1 | default_shipping               |
|          782 |              1 | disable_auto_group_change      |          571 |              1 | disable_auto_group_change      |
|          610 |              1 | dob                            |           11 |              1 | dob                            |
|          647 |              3 | children                       |           46 |              3 | children                       |
|          656 |              3 | children_count                 |           55 |              3 | children_count                 |
|          706 |              3 | custom_apply_to_products       |          494 |              3 | custom_apply_to_products       |
|          649 |              3 | custom_design                  |           48 |              3 | custom_design                  |
|          651 |              3 | custom_design_from             |           50 |              3 | custom_design_from             |
|          652 |              3 | custom_design_to               |           51 |              3 | custom_design_to               |
|          654 |              3 | custom_layout_update           |           53 |              3 | custom_layout_update           |
|          705 |              3 | custom_use_parent_settings     |          493 |              3 | custom_use_parent_settings     |
|          658 |              3 | default_sort_by                |          486 |              3 | default_sort_by                |
|          635 |              3 | description                    |           34 |              3 | description                    |
|          640 |              3 | display_mode                   |           39 |              3 | display_mode                   |
|          707 |              3 | filter_price_range             |          495 |              3 | filter_price_range             |
|          636 |              3 | image                          |           35 |              3 | image                          |
|          704 |              3 | include_in_menu                |          490 |              3 | include_in_menu                |
|          633 |              3 | is_active                      |           32 |              3 | is_active                      |
|          642 |              3 | is_anchor                      |           41 |              3 | is_anchor                      |
|          810 |              3 | is_spacer                      |          599 |              3 | is_spacer                      |
|          641 |              3 | landing_page                   |           40 |              3 | landing_page                   |
|          655 |              3 | level                          |           54 |              3 | level                          |
|          639 |              3 | meta_description               |           38 |              3 | meta_description               |
|          638 |              3 | meta_keywords                  |           37 |              3 | meta_keywords                  |
|          637 |              3 | meta_title                     |           36 |              3 | meta_title                     |
|          632 |              3 | name                           |           31 |              3 | name                           |
|          653 |              3 | page_layout                    |           52 |              3 | page_layout                    |
|          643 |              3 | path                           |           42 |              3 | path                           |
|          646 |              3 | path_in_store                  |           45 |              3 | path_in_store                  |
|          644 |              3 | position                       |           43 |              3 | position                       |
|          719 |              3 | thumbnail                      |          568 |              3 | thumbnail                      |
|          634 |              3 | url_key                        |           33 |              3 | url_key                        |
|          648 |              3 | url_path                       |           47 |              3 | url_path                       |
|          679 |              4 | color                          |           76 |              4 | color                          |
|          772 |              4 | color_description              |          469 |              4 | color_description              |
|          667 |              4 | cost                           |           64 |              4 | cost                           |
|          788 |              4 | country_of_manufacture         |          577 |              4 | country_of_manufacture         |
|          702 |              4 | created_at                     |          488 |              4 | created_at                     |
|          691 |              4 | custom_design                  |           86 |              4 | custom_design                  |
|          692 |              4 | custom_design_from             |           87 |              4 | custom_design_from             |
|          693 |              4 | custom_design_to               |           88 |              4 | custom_design_to               |
|          694 |              4 | custom_layout_update           |           89 |              4 | custom_layout_update           |
|          660 |              4 | description                    |           57 |              4 | description                    |
|          740 |              4 | e3ac01                         |          539 |              4 | e3ac01                         |
|          741 |              4 | e3ac02                         |          540 |              4 | e3ac02                         |
|          742 |              4 | e3ac03                         |          541 |              4 | e3ac03                         |
|          743 |              4 | e3ac04                         |          542 |              4 | e3ac04                         |
|          744 |              4 | e3ac05                         |          543 |              4 | e3ac05                         |
|          745 |              4 | e3ac06                         |          544 |              4 | e3ac06                         |
|          746 |              4 | e3ac07                         |          545 |              4 | e3ac07                         |
|          747 |              4 | e3ac08                         |          546 |              4 | e3ac08                         |
|          748 |              4 | e3ac09                         |          547 |              4 | e3ac09                         |
|          730 |              4 | e3cdes                         |          456 |              4 | e3cdes                         |
|          735 |              4 | e3col                          |          461 |              4 | e3col                          |
|          725 |              4 | e3cono                         |          451 |              4 | e3cono                         |
|          749 |              4 | e3cost                         |          548 |              4 | e3cost                         |
|          731 |              4 | e3csds                         |          457 |              4 | e3csds                         |
|          758 |              4 | e3ris1                         |          553 |              4 | e3ris1                         |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------------+
```

Before I run the query I can confirm that USA has no attribute_id = 51:

```
# There is no attribute_id before I begin the copy
mysql> select * from eav_attribute where attribute_id = 51;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

However the update causes a FK constraint error. Any idea why? How do I do this update successfully?

```
UPDATE eav_attribute usa_attribute, 
       com.eav_attribute com_attribute
SET usa_attribute.attribute_id = com_attribute.attribute_id
WHERE usa_attribute.entity_type_id = com_attribute.entity_type_id
      AND usa_attribute.attribute_code = com_attribute.attribute_code
```

Upholding foreign key constraints for table 'eav_attribute', entry '51', key 1 would lead to a duplicate entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I should have guessed - when getting a FK error I should check other tables referencing this table to see if ON UPDATE CASCADE might cause issues. To do this I did the following query:

```
SELECT table_name, 
       column_name, 
       constraint_name, 
       referenced_table_name, 
       referenced_column_name 
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE referenced_table_name = 'eav_attribute' AND table_schema = 'usa';

+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| table_name                           | column_name  | constraint_name                                                  | referenced_table_name | referenced_column_name |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| catalog_category_entity_datetime     | attribute_id | FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DTIME_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID                  | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
| catalog_category_entity_decimal      | attribute_id | FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID                    | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
| catalog_category_entity_int          | attribute_id | FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID                    | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
| catalog_category_entity_text         | attribute_id | FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_TEXT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID                   | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
......many more
| googlebase_attributes                | attribute_id | GOOGLEBASE_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE_ID                               | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
| salesrule_product_attribute          | attribute_id | FK_SALESRULE_PRD_ATTR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID                   | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
| weee_tax                             | attribute_id | FK_WEEE_TAX_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID              | eav_attribute         | attribute_id           |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

I was then able to do a quick select against these tables:

```
select * from catalog_category_entity_datetime where attribute_id = 51;
select * from catalog_category_entity_decimal where attribute_id = 51;
select * from catalog_category_entity_int where attribute_id = 51;
select * from catalog_category_entity_text where attribute_id = 51;
..... many more
select * from googlebase_attributes where attribute_id = 51;
select * from salesrule_product_attribute where attribute_id = 51;
select * from weee_tax where attribute_id = 51;
```

Then I could see that two tables had references to my first table (eav_attribute) with the values '51'.

Not sure how these got there, but since they dont match the FK I could happily delete them.